# WiX share code through custom actions

Tags: vbscript, wix, custom-action

I am using WiX 3.9 and I have a need for CustomActions. These CustomActions are executing VBScript, it does not matter what they are doing. I just want to know if I can share code trough different CustomActions.

What I have tried so far:

```xml
<Property Id="VBS_Logging">
  <![CDATA[
    MSgBox "Property injection worked"
  ]]>
</Property>

<CustomAction Id="ExecuteThis"
    Script="vbscript">
  [VBS_Logging]
  <![CDATA[
    MsgBox "Bye!"
  ]]>
</CustomAction>

<CustomAction Id="ExecuteSomewhereElse"
    Script="vbscript">
  [VBS_Logging]
  <![CDATA[
    MsgBox "Hi!"
  ]]>
</CustomAction>
```

Unfortunately this does not work, does somebody know an approach how I could achieve my goal?

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say that you want to share code here?

Please provide more details to help you with an answer to your problem

Comment: If I have one function, which I would use in different CustomActions with VBScript, how would you make this work with writing this function only once.

Comment: Well, you can have just one function but different custom action names all invoking the same vbscript. Is this what you want? Assume that i have a VBScript code. I can call the same vbscript code from custom action 1, custom action 2 and custom action 3. Ofcourse, if you are accessing public properties in each of these custom actions, you will need 3 corresponding type 51 custom actions to set the value of the special property: CustomActionData.  In short, having different custom action names is sufficient to reuse the same piece of code. Let me know if you need further help

Comment: Or were you looking for something like this:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372048(v=vs.85).aspx    . Look at custom action Type 6(VBScript stored in the binary table). Basically you only have one vbscript function, written once and stored in the binary table and invoked from multiple places.

Comment: I do not know, how I can create in WiX a specifc CustomAction. Could you extend my example above? So that it works with "sharing" this code.